# cannot install rails plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins

My problem is: `ruby script/plugin` is not working (I don't see any HTTP traffic, nor an error message or something) What can be failing? Did I forget to setup something?

My progress so far (using Windows XP):

- Unpacked hxxp://files.rubyforge.vm.bytemark.co.uk/rubyinstaller/ruby-1.9.1-p378-i386-mingw32.7z (to d:\prog\Ruby)
- Unpacked hxxp://files.rubyforge.mmmultiworks.com/rubyinstaller/devkit-3.4.5r3-20091110.7z (to d:\prog\Ruby\devkit)
- Unpacked hxxp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.1-p378.tar.gz (to d:\prog\Ruby\sources)
- Fixed `./devkit/msys/1.0.11/etc/fstab`
- Set `http_proxy=myproxy:8080`
- Unpacked hxxp://files.rubyforge.vm.bytemark.co.uk/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.5.zip (to a temp dir)
- Executed `rubygems-1.3.5\setup.rb`
- Added these gem sources:

  `http://gems.rubyinstaller.org`

  `http://gemcutter.org`

  `http://gems.rubyforge.org`
- Did `ruby gem install rails mysql mongrel`. No problems here.
- Created my first rails app, ran without problems with the default scaffolding (Mongrel, not WEBrick).
- Then I tried to install some rails plugins, like `ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold.git`. Didn't find anything.
- So I tried `ruby script/plugin discover`, and it does nothing (no error, just returns)

I'll probably have to do something about that `git` thingie next, but the fact that `plugin discover` is doing nothing makes me suspect something else is broken here? The web proxy access is working OK for the gems, and I don't see any HTTP requests being made from `plugin discover`...

Answer (score 1):

You can't install plugin by git if you have no git command. But git is not compatible in DOS console. You need use [MsysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)

You can install plugin by download the plugin from github and extract all source in your /vendor/plugins directory. All directory in this path are load by plugin

Comment: As I said I'll try to handle the `git` thing later. My problem is no plugin or repository is ever found (I tried many). There seems to be no HTTP access at all and no error message is shown?